# Spring Boot does not cache

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to use caching in Spring Boot. I have never used a cache in Spring Boot before. I looked at some tutorials and decided to use Caffeine to test it.

However, it is not cached. I can see with debug that the CacheConfig is loaded, but on each request the data is reloaded from the Catalog.getData().

So I thought it might be the debug mode. But even with println I see that it is not cached.

I have no cache configuration in application.properties.

It doesn't work without KeyGenerator either.

Have I forgotten something?

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**CacheConfig**

```java
import com.api.project.catalog.MyKeyGenerator;
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineConfig() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .initialCapacity(10);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeine) {
        CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
        caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine);
        return caffeineCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean("myKeyGenerator")
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new MyKeyGenerator();
    }
}
```

**KeyGenerator**

```java
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MyKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        return "my-concat-test-key";
    }
}
```

**Service**

```java
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Catalog {
    @Cacheable(value = "mycache", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator")
    public String getData(Locale locale, String key) {
        System.out.println(locale.toString() + " " + key);
        return locale.toString() + " " + key;
    }
}
```

**MyMessageSource**
MessageSource is configured and also works.

```java
public class MyMessageSource implements MessageSource {
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public String getMessage(String code, @Nullable Object[] args, @Nullable String defaultMessage, Locale locale) {
        // Some logic
        return new Catalog().getData(locale, code);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        // Some logic
        return new Catalog().getData(locale, code);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        // Some logic
        return new Catalog().getData(locale, code);
    }
}
```

Comment: please show where `getData()` is called

Comment: Have you tried makin CacheConfig extend from CachingConfigurerSupport?

Comment: @JAsgarov Catalog.getData() is called in MessageSource. MessageSource is configured and also works. I have added a very simplified example.

Comment: I have just extended the CacheConfig with org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport. But it is still not cached. CachingConfigurerSupport is declared with @deprecated.

Comment: I have defined @Cacheable on getMessage(). Now it is cached. I just don't understand why. Do you have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring 101: For Spring Context (the one that does all the magic of autowiring and such) to work you have to let Spring instantiate all the beans (Spring managed classes).

If you want the caching to work you need to make `MyMessageSource` a spring managed bean, and let Spring instantiate it and the `Catalog` class.

So basically just add `@Service` or sth on top of the class and only call it from classes that autowire it (don't instantiate it yourself)